# Vector<tuple>, make_tuple<int, ignore, float>

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I create a vector of tuples:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int*, bool, int*>> *DataStucture;
```

Next I want to iterate over a data set to get only the first element of each tuple.

Is this legal:

```
DataStructure -> push_back(std::make_tuple(some_pointer_to_some_int_value, std::ignore, std::ignore));
```

In next round of data set scanning, I compare the value of some_int_value and upon matching I set following two elements of DataStructure:

```
DataStructure -> push_back(std::make_tuple(std::ignore, some_bool_value, some_pointer_to_some_int_value2);
```

I am not sure what exactly `std::ignore` is for. I tried checking cpp reference website but I did not get it.

Comment: "some_int_value" is not the same thing as "some pointer to an int value".

Comment: @[Sam Varshavchik] changed to pointer. Sorry.

Comment: First, your second operation is not exactly "set following two elements", it's adding new tuple. Second, you don't need `std::ignore`, use `nullptr` instead. `std::ignore` is used when _unpacking_ tuples into different variables, not to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on my previous comment, you cannot use `std::ignore` here, because it can be used only as lvalue, but really you don't need to either. Just use `nullptr` or any "default" value instead:

```
DataStructure->push_back(std::make_tuple(some_pointer_to_some_int_value, false, nullptr));
```

`std::ignore` should be used if you want to unpack your tuple into different values like this:

```
int* p; 
bool b; 
for (auto& tuple : *DataStructure) {
    std::tie(p,b,std::ignore) = tuple;
    // p now have value of first element of tuple
    // b now have value of second element of tuple
}
```

On an unrelated note, your second operation does not set values of existing tuple, it adds new one. Also, why use pointer to a `vector` instead of `vector` itself or at least `std::unique_ptr`? It is generaly considered better to omit unnecessary "naked" pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I was reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore.

And I think you cannot do that because std::ignore is only used as lvalue placeholders.

For example, if you have a return value that you don't want to use, you can do the following.

```
std::ignore = AFunctionWithAReturnValue();
```

It cannot be used as a part of rvalue. For your purpose, I'd just fill in placeholder values during the first scanning like this:

```
std::make_tuple(some_pointer_to_some_int_value, false, nullptr);
```